# Facebook Like Button iFrame covered by Website Content

Tags: blogs, facebook-like

I successfully added the Facebook Like button to each my blog's posts.

The problem: posts whose titles are longer than one line cover the Like button. (See [my blog here](http://www.trevormckendrick.com/page/2/). Scroll half way down to posts with the problem, please.)

Here's what I know:

(1)the "headline_area" div includes the title and the author name. The content body of each posts is always directly beneath that div.

(2) When the title of a post is only **one** line, the Facebook Like button stays up again the bottom of the title. Because the "headline_area" div is consistent, the body of the post stays below both the title, author, and facebook like buttons.

(3) When the title is **two** lines, the "headline_area" div remains the same, but the Like button gets pushed down by the second line. The post content stays up against the headline_area div, thus overlapping the Like button.

I hope that is clear. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with CSS `.headline_area` style. It has defined fixed height to `height: 80px` (`custom.css:7`). Try removing it and changing facebook like iframe height.

Comment: This worked. I removed the height of the .headline_area div and then decreased the iFrame height from 60px to 25px.

Why did that work? Why would the content cover the iFrame when the height is 60 but not 25?

PS - Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Previous version didn't worked because .headline_area div content was higher than 80px and was overflowing from fixed size div. I told you to change size of like button iframe because it was highier than it's content and would leave empty space between headline and entry content.
You can try using Google Chrome developers tools or Firebug(for firefox) to see what is/was happening.
You're welcome : )